# Pandas - drop function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I want to drop rows from a dataframe, based on the condition that the value of a specific column is in a list. If this is not the case I want the row to be dropped.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance

As an example, if the value in column 'C' is not inside the list l, I want to drop the entire row

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(20, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

l = [4, 6, 23, 45, 79]
```

Comment: Can you please provide some text data, what you have tried, and what results you are expecting?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Or, what is the condition? Which value? Edit the question.

Comment: oh sorry, edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: any(x.isin(l)), axis=1)]
```

if only one column must be

and if, only `C`:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x["C"] in l, axis=1)]
```

or, if all columns:

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: all(x.isin(l)), axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

`df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], columns=["a", "b"])`

`df[(df.a.isin([3]) == False)]`

This will only leave those lines in the data frame, whose a-value is not in the list given to isin, i.e. that where it is not 3.